# How can I prove this lemma?

Tags: calculus, functions, supremum-and-infimum

How can I prove that for every function g that is bounded in interval I:

$\sup_{I}(g) - \inf_{I}(g) = \sup_{x,y \in I} |g(x) - g(y)|$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.